# Middleware and beforeFilter auth won't work

Tags: php, laravel-5, middleware

I defined a resource route group

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api/v1'], function() {
  Route::resource('words', 'WordController');
});
```

and I created a controller for all that routes. I want to set basic authentication for all requests so I added to the constructor of `WordController`:  `$this->beforeFilter('auth.basic');` But there is no effect. I still can get all words without any username and password provided. Does someone know why?

```
class WordController extends ApiController {

    protected $wordTransformer;

    function __construct(WordTransformer $wordTransformer)
    {
        $this->wordTransformer = $wordTransformer;

        $this->beforeFilter('auth.basic');
        //$this->middleware('auth.basic');

    }

    public function index()
    {
        $words = Word::all();
        return $this->respond([
            'words' => $this->wordTransformer->transformCollection($words->all())
        ]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using laravel 5, you can use middleware that replace filter. Using middleware is becoming the preferred practice and way of thinking about decorating your routes. Why your code not working because auth.basic is a type of middleware not filter.

You can attach the middleware in controller since you are using Route::group.
See the code below how to attach it.

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api/v1', 'middleware' => 'auth.basic'], function() {
  Route::resource('words', 'WordController');
});
```

You can see at the above code use middleware name "auth.basic". How do you know the middleware. Before you can use the middleware, you must register the middleware by define the middleware in /app/Http/Kernel.php. If you open that file you can see the code below.

```
/**
 * The application's route middleware.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => 'App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate',
    'auth.basic' => 'Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth',
    'guest' => 'App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated',
];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like below. authenticate user during the routing rather then controller.

```
Route::get('home', array('before' => 'auth', 'do' => function()
{
    // your action here
}));


Route::filter('auth',function(){
     if(Auth::guest())
         return Redirect::to('login');

});
```